# v-if doesn't recognize value from array of object

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a vueJS file and have a component :

```
<div class="panel-heading" v-on:click="displayValue(feature.id)">
         {{ feature.nom }}
</div>
<div class="panel-body" v-if="getDisplay(feature.id)">
          foo
</div>
```

my function `displayValue(id)` :

```
displayValue(id){
    for(let i =0; i<this.product_site.displayFeatures.length;i++){
        if (this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].idFeature === id){
            this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show = !this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show
        }
    }
    console.log(this.product_site.displayFeatures)
},
```

First I am not very happy with that. I trie to do a .find but it didn't work :

```
this.product_site.displayFeatures.find(function(a){
      a.idFeature === id
}).show = true
```

But I had an error telling me `can not read 'show' of undefined`

and my function `getDisplay(id)`

```
 getDisplay(id){
            this.product_site.displayFeatures.forEach(function(a){
                if(a.idFeature === id){
                    return a.show
                }
            })
        }
```

same as before if I try with a find.

Anyway, I thought it would work with that, but when I do `console.log(this.product_sites.displayFeatures)` I have the array with the modified value but `foo` is not shown

Comment: In your `displayValue()` method , instead of `this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show = !this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show` can you try `this.$set(this.product_site.displayFeatures[i], 'show', !this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show)`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna of if I just copy past what you sais I have a weird error : `main.js:42347 Uncaught TypeError: exp.trim is not a function` but I tried with : `                        this.$set(`product_site.displayFeatures[${i}].show`, !this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show)` and I don't have any error message but the problem stay the same

Comment: Is `show` the only property or there are othe properties on `displayFeatures[i]` object?

Comment: there is also idFeature @VamsiKrishna

Comment: ok try this...make `show` an array like this : `show:[false]` and try ... `this.$set(this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show, 0, !this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show[0]);`

Comment: Had the exp.trim is not a function error so I try with : `this.$set(\`product_site.displayFeatures[${i}].show[${0}]\`, !this.product_site.displayFeatures[i].show[0]);` and the same, the value change but the `foo` is not displayed @VamsiKrishna